# Roku_Ads.brs library error on Roku 4 with Roku Advertising Framework

Tags: ads, roku

Despite adding `bs_libs_required=roku_ads_lib` in manifest, I am getting

An error occurred while attempting to compile the application:
-------> BS lib provider not found: roku_ads_lib

Note: The roku build is running fine on Roku3 with this code. This error is occurring on Roku4. Are there any other parameters needed on Roku4. Or did Roku4 does not support dfp ads?

Comment: What exactly version of the firmware? Is your user account outside US?

Comment: The version is 7.1.0. No, the account is not outside US.

Comment: I am at a loss. Please post at http://forums.roku.com/viewforum.php?f=34 so that Roku staff may see it.

Comment: I have the same problem, have You found any solutions at all?

Comment: Hi, yes, the solution worked for me but I am not sure if it will work for you. Still, the solution is to write bs_libs_required=roku_ads_lib in the end and add an extra line. Yes, this is the solution. I got an email from roku developers saying this and it worked for me. You can try it too.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse, open up the Manifest file. There should be an option towards the bottom left that says "Requires RAF". Check that box and it will automatically add that line of code to your manifest.